# Missing pub folder path from static content in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I deploy my site on centos7 and deploy content as well which is in pub folder.But when i inspect element it shows path like in screenshot attatch without pub folder name.Some files are missing as well from path.Any solution

[image]

Comment: Are you running on nginx or Apache? Besides that check the static front end url in the configuration

Comment: i m using  nginx centos 7

Comment: Did you fix this issue?  I am facing the same :(

Comment: did you fix the issue?

Comment: anyone fixed this issue? I have same this :(

Answer (score 1):

replace main .htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php

Answer (score 0):

Anyone with this issue on 2.4.2, I hope this helps save you hours of headaches. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-dirs.html

/vendor/magento/framework/App/Filesystem/DirectoryList.php has some changed URL_PATHs from previous versions, the ***pub*** part has been removed for some reason, causing the broken paths to static files. Replace the pub and all is well:

self::MEDIA => [parent::PATH => 'pub/media', parent::URL_PATH => 'pub/media'],
self::STATIC_VIEW => [parent::PATH => 'pub/static', parent::URL_PATH => 'pub/static'],
self::PUB => [parent::PATH => 'pub', parent::URL_PATH => 'pub'],
self::UPLOAD => [parent::PATH => 'pub/media/upload', parent::URL_PATH => 'pub/media/upload'],

Then rerun upgrade commands:

rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0):

Update in your index.php file

Path: pub/index.php

DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'pub', DirectoryList::URL_PATH => '**pub**'],
DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::PATH => 'pub/media', DirectoryList::URL_PATH => '**pub/media**'],
DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => '**pub/static**']

```
<?php
/**
 * Public alias for the application entry point
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http;

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER;
$params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = [
     DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'pub', DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'pub'],
     DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::PATH => 'pub/media', DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'pub/media'],
     DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'pub/static']
];

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```